# What is the property called wherein permuting the input tuple of a function results in the same permutation in the output tuple?

Tags: functions, permutations, terminology, group-actions, convention

A function *f* takes an *n*-tuple as input and gives an *n*-tuple as output.

If permuting the elements of the input *n*-tuple of this function always results in the same permutation of the elements of the output *n*-tuple of this function, what is this property called?

For example, if $f(x_1, x_2, x_3) = (y_1, y_2, y_3)$, then $f(x_1, x_3, x_2) = (y_1, y_3, y_2)$.

Comment: @lulu No, a symmetric function is one such that f(x1, x2) = f(x2, x1), that is, permuting the inputs does not change the output at all. I'm asking for the property that if f(x1, x2) = (y1, y2), then f(x2, x1) = (y2, y1), that is, permuting the input does change the output by applying the same permutation to the output.

Comment: Is this supposed to hold for all possible permutations?  If so, your function is "invariant under (or commutes with) the natural $S_n$-action."

Comment: Is there anything you can prove about this property? I just tried to set $x_2=x_3=z$ and you immediately get $f_2(x_1,z,z)=f_3(x_1,z,z)$. It feels like there could be much more. Do you maybe have some non-trivial example?

Comment: @Randall "Invariant under" would imply $f(\sigma(x_1,...,x_k))=f(x_1,...,x_k)$, which is not what's going on here; your parenthetical "commutes with" is correct ($f\sigma=\sigma f$).

Comment: ah, you are correct.